# How to see the contents of deployed datasource?

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I've inherited a project (without a handy handover) that contains reports published to a Reporting Server (2005).
MY SSRS knowledge is 4 years stale, so I need your help.

I need to edit one of the published reports, is this possible?
 I also want to peek into the Data Source on the RS, because that's probably where I can change stuff.

I'll add more info as I get a better understanding of what exactly to ask.

EDIT: I found a project for some of the reports, opened up in VS2005 BI.

Still, how do I see where the Data Source gets its data?

It brings back 56 fields but I don't know which tables/stored procs/queries are used to get these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can.

1st -  to edit the published reports: Browse to the folder containing the report source you want on report server (web server). On the right side click 'Show Details'. Now click the properties icon under the 'Edit' column. Near the bottom you will see two links: Edit & Update. Click edit and the source RDL file will start to download. This is the actual report source.

You can import this right into a VS2005 report project and have full access for modifications.

2nd - As to the project you found: After opening an RDL file for editing, click the 'Data' tab. directly under that you will see a drop down list labeled 'Dataset:'. A report can have one or more datasets. These are the actual queries that generate report data. Also clicking '...' will allow you to see other properties of each dataset, such as parameters, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a profiler on your server, then run your report. The profiler give you most info about your query or stored procedure.